Batch script does not output file when limited user runs it from an administrator task manually
The Problem:
I want to let a limited user restart a Service. This requires admin privileges, and thus the limited user is unable to restart individual services. I also want to create a timestamp file when this is done.
The Solution
After some research, I came across a workaround that allows a limited user to execute a privileged action by abusing the Task Scheduler. I was able to accomplish this by doing the following:

Create a batch file with the privileged task (restart service in this case)
Create a Scheduled Task that has an action to run the privileged task.
Configure the scheduled task to run as the System account and with Highest Privileges.
Create a shortcut to "schtasks.exe" and pass arguments to run the created task (C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "<task_name>")
Provide this shortcut to the limited user account (such as on the desktop of the user)
Run the shortcut to run the scheduled task.

But alas! It was not that easy, as the limited user is unable to see the task, let alone call it, due to insufficient permissions.
So workaround 2 is applied.
I come across this PowerShell script
credit: https://michlstechblog.info/blog/windows-run-task-scheduler-task-as-limited-user/
$scheduler = New-Object -ComObject "Schedule.Service"
$scheduler.Connect()
$task = $scheduler.GetFolder("").GetTask("Restart_RTC_And_BT")
$sec = $task.GetSecurityDescriptor(0xF)
$sec = $sec + '(A;;GRGX;;;AU)'
$task.SetSecurityDescriptor($sec, 0)

This is basically changing the permissions on the task to allow the limited user to read and execute the task.
The Script
setlocal

set "YYYY=%DATE:~10,4%"
set "MM=%DATE:~4,2%"
set "DD=%DATE:~7,2%"
set "HH=%TIME:~0,2%"
set "NN=%TIME:~3,2%"
set "SS=%TIME:~6,2%"

if "%HH:~0,1%"==" " set HH=0%HH:~1,1%

set "FILENAME=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%NN%-%SS%.errortime"

set "OUTPUT_DIR=C:\Log"

copy nul "%OUTPUT_DIR%\%FILENAME%"

endlocal

net stop "Bluetooth Support Service"

timeout /t 5 /nobreak > nul

net start "Bluetooth Support Service"

The Bug
So when the shortcut is clicked it runs the task correctly, and the script begins execution, however, the timestamp file is not created.
My theory is that the script is running in "non-interactive" mode (since the task is running as system) and this is somehow preventing it from accessing explorer.exe? But I have no clue.
I would really appreciate some help if anyone has some idea of why something like this could happen. I just want a timestamp file of when the task gets run, so I am happy to explore other ideas as well.

Why the timestamp file?  That information is in the event log.  Well written and formatted Q.

@echo off

for /f Usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^<^>. %%G in =;(`
     call "%%__AppDir__%%wbem\wmic.exe" OS Get LocalDateTime /Format:xml ^| "%%__AppDir__%%find.exe" "VALUE"
   `);= do set "_dt=%%~G" %=> 20240718215213 current date time < =%

set "_Y=%_dt:~0,4%"       %=  2024                   Year        =%
set "_M=%_dt:~4,2%"       %=      07                 Month       =%
set "_D=%_dt:~6,2%"       %=        18               Day         =%
set "_H=%_dt:~8,2%"       %=          21             Hour        =%
set "_S=%_dt:~10,2%"      %=            52           Minute      =%
set "_N=%_dt:~12,2%"      %=              13         Millisecond =%

set "_FName=%_Y%-%_M%-%_D%_%_H%-%_S%-%_N%.errortime"
%= FName=> 2024 - 07 - 18 _ 21 - 52 - 13 .errortime =%

set "_out_dir=C:\Log"
cd.>"%_out_Dir%\%_FName%"

"%__AppDir__%net.exe" stop "Bluetooth Support Service"
"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /t 05 /nobreak >nul
"%__AppDir__%net.exe" start "Bluetooth Support Service"


wmic.exe OS Get LocalDateTime /Format:xml

Get %date% and %time% without interference in the layout due to language, location and/or any configuration required by user/software, to have a more reliable and predictable layout for definitions of desired variables and values ​​such as year, month, day, hours, etc.

In PowerShell:

$dt=Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss-ff

# Or..

$dt=(Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss-ff")


wmic ... ^| "%%__AppDir__%%find.exe" "VALUE"

Also get the wmic output strings without additional line breaks and/or blank characters

"%__AppDir__%net.exe"
"%__AppDir__%find.exe"
"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe"

>set | find "path" /i
HOMEPATH=\Users\....
Path=...;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;...
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

My personal suggestion, use the absolute path or at least the system variables that respond to paths and the respective extensions for the executables involved in executing your bat, you cannot predict that any third-party bat will be using one or more executable names in some bat or something like that, in addition to considering that some of the definitions of the search order for extensions (PATHEXT)have been changed/edited and result in executing another bat file, cmd, exe, com, etc..

command 
...
command  %=> some strings <=%  
...
%=> other strings <=%
...
command

Just a way to add a line or add a comment to the same line

